# Some strange when using Promise in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have a function that returns a promise object. This is my code

```
var foo = function(){
    // doSomething() is a promise object
    return doSomething().then(() => {
        Promise.resolve('Hello');
    });
};

foo().then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    // res = undefined but not "Hello"
});
```

I thought function `foo` would return the promise object and I would get the string "Hello". But I get undefined. Why?

Comment: You're missing a `return` before `Promise.resolve`. However, actually you don't need that at all, and could just return the string `Hello`. You could make it even simpler by using the concise body form of arrow function, leaving off the `{}`, and just say `.then(() => 'Hello')`.

Comment: Thanks, It works and looks better.

Comment: Can you please show your `doSomething` method?

Comment: @timothyclifford The implementation of `doSomething` is by definition irrelevant to the behavior of this code, as long as it returns a promise as the OP has already stated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a return before Promise.resolve, so it should be

```
var foo = function(){
    return doSomething().then(() => {
        return Promise.resolve('Hello');
        ^^^^^^
    });
};
```

However, actually you don't need that at all, and could just return the string Hello.

```
var foo = function(){
    return doSomething().then(() => {
        return 'Hello';
    });
};
```

You could make it even simpler by using the concise body form of arrow function, leaving off the `{}`.

```
var foo = function(){
    return doSomething().then(() => 'Hello');
};
```